# How to close a mocked connection object in easymock

Tags: java, easymock

I have used easymock for creating a java.sql.Connection mock object(con). My doubt is

- Should i use con=null for cleanup or
- con.close() for cleanup ?

In my opinion it should be the first one but still wanted to clear my doubts.

Comment: What does the mock object need?  Do you need to do either?  I usually finish with `verify(mockObject);`

Comment: Hi. I just want to cleanup all mock object i have created in @After method of JUnit.
e.g. If i have created mock object obj of ABC class then i simply do obj=null
Since connection object we generally cleanup by con.close hence my confusion for mock connection object cleanup

Comment: AFAIK, there is no particular reason to do either.  The mock object is unlikely to be so large that you need to "help" the GC by clearing it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Does this mean easymock/JUnit takes care of cleaning up the mock object once a particular JUnit complete its run ?

Comment: Generally speaking, there isn't anything to do to clean up a mock object, so it doesn't matter whether you try to clean it up or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a mock object so it will not be creating actual connection to the database. So, the first one should suffice in my opinion. If you call `conn.close()`, you will have to mock it anyways.